# Is paging going on non-stop even if I have plenty of memory?

Tags: windows-10, memory, paging

My laptop has 16GB and only 50% is used. My PC is at rest, with no foreground activity and no known background activity from my running aps.

Why is Windows 10 still churning the disk most of the time?

I suppose there must be significant disk read/write before the disk light comes on. What are all these disk activities?

If I have lots of RAM, shouldn't disk activity be only from applications?

Comment: Don't guess, use Resource Monitor to find out which files are active.

Comment: Your question body doesn't agree with your title. You have assumed paging is responsible & are asking about how to identify that, rather than asking what may actually be responsible. This is known as an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 1):

Windows likes to reserve a bit of RAM at all times, so it will generally start hitting the page file before all of the RAM is used up. You can view your page file usage by going to Resource Monitor and finding the entry for the Page File.

I doubt Windows is hitting the Page File if only 50% of the RAM is occupied. It is possible of course, but it shouldn't be happening by default. Most likely what is happening is your system disk is being accessed for other reasons. The OS is constantly going back to the system disk to load some file or other into RAM. This is why systems with SSDs are so noticeably faster than a Hard Drive, because of this constant cycle of loading files. If the disk usage is fluctuating up and down then this is what is happening.

If the disk usage is at a consistent rate, then that may be indicative of another issue. If you are just sitting on the desktop not doing anything at all, the disk usage should be around 0% for the most part.

There are a few things you could do a troubleshooting steps if you are interested.

1. Open up a command prompt as an administrator and run the command `sfc /scannow`. This will prompt the system to do an integrity check on the system files, and then repair any damage.
2. In a command prompt as an administrator, run the command `chkdsk c:` this will tell the system to scan the system disk for any errors. If it finds any it will prompt you to run the command again, with the /f parameter. As an example `chkdsk c: /f`
3. Other than this, disable any startup apps which may be running that you do not need, make sure the system is up to date, run a scan with windows defender to rule out any viruses. Malwarebytes free version is a pretty decent option as well.

Comment: Windows will start to page at about 50% , certainly with only 16GB RAM, but not in any really meaningful way. It's kind of 'prepping up' for when it might be needed. It's certainly not paging in & out with every app focus swap at that point, though. Personally, I find it irritates my OCD rather than causes any issues. Mac doesn't do it until a much greater percentage is used. Right now I'm using 47 of 64GB & my swap file is 0 bytes.

Comment: I have not noticed Windows paging data at only 50% RAM, but that doesn’t mean it isn’t happening. That’s interesting. I think it depends on how many apps you have running at the same time. In my experience the paging threshold has been closer to 75%. Still too low really, but it is what it is. As the saying goes, “unused ram is wasted ram.”

Comment: Indeed. tbh, it's not something I've truly studied, just kind of noticed in passing. Mainly I'm a Mac user so I'm more familiar with that - now up to 50GB used still with 0 byte page file, after 15 days uptime. https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5hRZ.png

Comment: Perhaps how much RAM you have is a difference maker. I have 32 GB and can go up to 90% usage without hitting the page file. Someone with 4GB may see page usage at 40%.